# How to use a custom Collector in a groupingBy operation

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream, collectors

The [Oracle trails on reduction](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/reduction.html) with streams gives an example of how to convert a collection of people into a map containing the average age based on gender.  It uses the following `Person` class and code:

```
public class Person {
    private int age;

    public enum Sex {
        MALE,
        FEMALE
    }

    private Sex sex;

    public Person (int age, Sex sex) {
        this.age = age;
        this.sex = sex;
    }

    public int getAge() { return this.age; }

    public Sex getSex() { return this.sex; }
}

Map<Person.Sex, Double> averageAgeByGender = roster
    .stream()
    .collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy(
            Person::getSex,                      
            Collectors.averagingInt(Person::getAge)));
```

The above stream code works great, but I wanted to see how to do the same operation while using a *custom* implementation of a collector.  I could find no complete example of how to do this either on Stack Overflow or the net.  As to why we might want to do this, as an example, perhaps we would want to compute some kind of weighted average involving the age.  In this case, the default behavior of `Collectors.averagingInt` would not suffice.

Comment: Not sure if it helps in this case but there is also `Collectors.summarizingInt`, which returns an [IntSummaryStatistics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/IntSummaryStatistics.html) and is quite helpful when `Collectors.averagingInt` does not suffice.

Comment: @kapex That's helpful, but my intention was to give some usable boiler plate code for cases where the canned collectors _don't_ cover one's requirements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use [`Collector.of(Supplier, BiConsumer, BinaryOperator, [Function,] Characteristics...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html#of-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.BiConsumer-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-java.util.stream.Collector.Characteristics...-) for those cases:

```
Collector.of(() -> new double[2],
        (a, t) -> { a[0] += t.getAge(); a[1]++; },
        (a, b) -> { a[0] += b[0]; a[1] += b[1]; return a; },
        a -> (a[1] == 0) ? 0.0 : a[0] / a[1])
)
```

Although it might be more readable to define a `PersonAverager`:

```
class PersonAverager {
    double sum = 0;
    int count = 0;

    void accept(Person p) {
        sum += p.getAge();
        count++;
    }

    PersonAverager combine(PersonAverager other) {
        sum += other.sum;
        count += other.count;
        return this;
    }

    double average() {
        return count == 0 ? 0 : sum / count;
    }
}
```

and use it as:

```
Collector.of(PersonAverager::new,
        PersonAverager::accept,
        PersonAverager::combine,
        PersonAverager::average)
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen you can accept it now, these are the only ways to create a custom `Collector`... and yes, most definitely 1+

Comment: I was writing an answer with this exact content... +1 One improvement would be to  use a well-named utility method in which you define the `PersonAverager` as a local class and you return the collector created with `Collector.of`. This way, you end up with very readable code: `Map<Person.Sex, Double> averageAgeBySex = list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getSex, averagingInt(Person::getAge)));`, where `averagingInt` is the name of the static utility method.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner To be honest, I though about doing that, but you already have `Collectors.averingInt/Long/Double()` that does exactly that (and much better for `double`). I thought it would be more important to keep it simple here as it makes it easier to generalize for when you want to do something else than averaging.

Comment: I agree, this is your answer. Besides, using a static method is a matter of taste and it doesn't deserve a new answer. For this case (averagingX) it doesn't make sense to use neither a custom collector nor a static method, but for more complex cases, it might pay off.

Answer (score 3):

This answer, which has been tested, is based off a bunch of different sources.  The source code for [`Collectors#averagingInt`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/stream/Collectors.java) was helpful in figuring out the lambda syntax used below.  The supplier used is a `Double[]` array of size two.  The first index is used to store the cumulative person ages, while the second index stores the counts.

```
public class PersonCollector<T extends Person> implements Collector<T, double[], Double> {
    private ToIntFunction<Person> mapper;

    public PersonCollector(ToIntFunction<Person> mapper) {
        this.mapper = mapper;
    }

    @Override
    public Supplier<double[]> supplier() {
        return () -> new double[2];
    }

    @Override
    public BiConsumer<double[], T> accumulator() {
        return (a, t) -> { a[0] += mapper.applyAsInt(t); a[1]++; };
    }

    @Override
    public BinaryOperator<double[]> combiner() {
        return (a, b) -> { a[0] += b[0]; a[1] += b[1]; return a; };
    }

    @Override
    public Function<double[], Double> finisher() {
        return a -> (a[1] == 0) ? 0.0 : a[0] / a[1];
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Characteristics> characteristics() {
        // do NOT return IDENTITY_FINISH here, which would bypass
        // the custom finisher() above
        return Collections.emptySet();
    }
}

List<Person> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new Person(34, Person.Sex.MALE));
list.add(new Person(23, Person.Sex.MALE));
list.add(new Person(68, Person.Sex.MALE));
list.add(new Person(14, Person.Sex.FEMALE));
list.add(new Person(58, Person.Sex.FEMALE));
list.add(new Person(27, Person.Sex.FEMALE));

final Collector<Person, double[], Double> pc = new PersonCollector<>(Person::getAge);

Map<Person.Sex, Double> averageAgeBySex = list
  .stream()
  .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getSex, pc));

System.out.println("Male average: " + averageAgeBySex.get(Person.Sex.MALE));
System.out.println("Female average: " + averageAgeBySex.get(Person.Sex.FEMALE));
```

This outputs:

```
Male average: 41.666666666666664
Female average: 33.0
```

Note above that we pass the method reference `Person::getAge` to the custom collector, which maps each `Person` in the collection to an integer age value.  Also, we do not return `Characteristics.IDENTITY_FINISH` from the `characateristics()` method.  Doing so would mean that our custom `finisher()` would be bypassed.

Comment: @Eugene Is it legal for a primitive type to appear inside a generic diamond `<>`?  I tried making your changes but got errors.

Comment: You can also use the `Collector.of(...)` factory method to create a custom collector.

Comment: Right, just `Collector.of(() -> new double[2], (a, t) -> { a[0] += mapper.applyAsInt(t); a[1]++; }, (a, b) -> { a[0] += b[0]; a[1] += b[1]; return a; }, a -> a[1] == 0? 0.0: a[0] / a[1])` will do.

Comment: I welcome other answers.  If you could comment on why using the completely inline version of `Collector.of` would be appropriate over the more verbose version I used, that would good.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen IMO *much* easier to read and we read code *a lot* more than we write...

Comment: @Eugene Fair enough.  To be honest though, I found reading the inline version tough, because I didn't know the order of the components.  But, I'm sure once one gets familiar with the API, there is an advantage.